# Magento 1.9.1 Static Block not visible in Front End

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, frontend, static-block, cms-block

I have created the static block in `cms/static blocks`

Then added the following code to `catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock(‘cms/block’)->setBlockId(‘your_block_identifier’)->toHtml() ?>
```

also enabled `Allow Symlinks` in `system > configuration > Developer > Template Settings`

Is there any suggestions?

Comment: Please check store setting for this  status block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change **`** with **'**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_identifier')->toHtml() ?>
```